# trim and vlookup functions not working in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, trim

I am trying to use vlook up on the following spreadsheet. It repeatedly came up as N/A so I thought it has to do with formatting or extra spaces in my cells.

So now I have two problems.

1. Vlookup returning 0 when it shouldn't.

   `=VLOOKUP(C2,X1:Z1252,2,FALSE)`

[image]

2. My trim function isn't working either, it's just repeating the first cell

[image]

Also, as they are all formatted as numbers I can't figure out why the numbers are sometimes right or left aligned.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing cells with text content and with numbers content. These might look the same, and even aligned the same (if you manually align left or right), but you have to check the formatting of the cells (and re-format if necessary) to get it right (just select cells, right-click, and "format cells".

TRIM is a function that only works on text.

Please also note that I personally have found it difficult to make VLOOKUP work reliably with numbers, in particular if you want an exact match (by using the FALSE parameter).

As your lookup values are Id's I think it is better to convert all of them (i.e. both columns C and X) into Text values.